# Using Python/Django to update GitHub

Tags: python, django, git, github

This is the broken code I wrote to update a GitHub repo from my Django powered web-based code-editor, see https://github.com/DjangoCoder/DjangoGUI/blob/master/projects/views.py line 763. How do I rewrite this code to actually work?

```
def update_github(request, project_slug):
    print 'UPDATE GITHUB\n' * 100
    project = Project.objects.get(created_by=request.user, slug=project_slug)
    import pexpect
    child = pexpect.spawn('/bin/bash',)
    import sys
    child.logfile = sys.stdout 
    print 'a'
    child.sendline('cd %s' % (project.get_current_directory()))
    print 'b'
    child.sendline('git add *')
    child.sendline('git commit -m "commit"')
    print 'c'
    child.sendline('git push -u origin master')
    print 'd'
    child.sendline('ssgmssgm2')
    print 'e'

    return HttpResponse('')
```

Comment: Could you use [this python git library](http://gitorious.org/git-python#more) instead, which was specifically made for this?  Documentation found [here](http://packages.python.org/GitPython/0.3.2/tutorial.html)

Answer (score 0):

i think you should use the github api to this kind of work.
see  http://developer.github.com/v3/  more more details.